# Anyone using JRuby-Rack with Rails 3?

Tags: jetty, jruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rack

Is anyone else out there running Rails 3 and JRuby-Rack, or Jetty and Rails 3?  Any trick to it?  I'm going insane with some debugging, and at this point I just want to know that it's possible.

Comment: could you provide some details? any error messages? log sniplets?

Comment: Sure.  We're running Jetty 7 with a custom startup script, and it worked great with Rails 2.x.  Now that we've upgraded to Rails 3, the app is totally broken.  Normally, no problem:  Check your exceptions and errors, then chase it down.

Unfortunately, it's not emitting any error messages or log information *at all* on the Rails side of things.  Log4j works dandy, and reports that everything's cool from Jetty's perspective.  However, Rails just silently sits there, and when you try to access the app it gives you an error page.  No errors, no nothing.

I suspect jruby-rack, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Towynlin's link looks like a good starting place.  I'll do some more debugging, and then ask a new question if I get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These instructions work for me:
http://mathias-biilmann.net/2010/2/jruby-and-rails-3-beta-step-by-step

Comment: This question and answer are now a bit outdated since the current version of rails is 3.1.0, but just for posterity, you can find [the blog entry I linked to](http://web.archive.org/web/20101025005010/http://mathias-biilmann.net/2010/2/jruby-and-rails-3-beta-step-by-step) on archive.org.

Answer (score 0):

i am using jetty-rails + rails3 for a couple of projects. jetty-rails need to be fixed , require "activesupport" need to be changed to require "active_support" (for activesupport 3.0.3) and you have also do 'require "active_support/all"' to include hash extensions (otherwise symbolize! & reverse_merge method will raise exceptions.. right now trying to fix some jruby-rack issues.. (Rack::Runtime not loaded)..will update once thats done.