# Is JRuby ready for Rails 3?

Tags: jruby, ruby-on-rails-3

There are several posts floating around on getting it running, but haven't seen any definitive guides on what is and what's not working. Is it ready for production?

According to http://jruby.org/ it's 1.8.7 compatible and 1.9 coming soon.

**Update** [@nicksieger](https://twitter.com/#!/nicksieger) of Engine Yard replied to my question via twitter:

> absolutely, I wouldn't hesitate. If there are any hiccups they should be minor, and easily fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trevor, also see the [original Rails 3 release blog post](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/8/29/rails-3-0-it-s-done) which states that it was designed to work with JRuby 1.5 (1.5.2 at the time of the post).

Answer (score 0):

yes Jruby is ready

this article is old but it helped

http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2010/02/24/jruby-and-rails-3-sitting-in-a-tree

plus this Question was asked before

[Anyone using JRuby-Rack with Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278319/anyone-using-jruby-rack-with-rails-3)

Comment: That question was a little different and didn't get answered very thoroughly. Would love to see some answers by people who are using jruby/rails3 in production successfully and if there were any hiccups along the way.